# How to dynamically add an object with an array key to an object literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-literal

I have an existing object literal:

```
var words=[
    {
"word":"callous",
"definition":"uncaring",
"examples": [
   {"sentence":"How could you be so callous?"},
   {"sentence":"What a callous thing to say!"},
   {"sentence":"That showed a callous disregard for the consequences."}
]
}
```

];

I'm trying to add more objects dynamically as follows:

```
var obj={};
obj.word="nextword";
obj.definition ="nextword definition";
obj.examples= ???;
for (var i = 0; i < nextwordSentencesArray.length; i++) {
 ??? obj.examples.sentence.push(nextwordSentencesArray[i]);
}
words.push(obj);
```

I have tried various options at -???- but nothing works. Advice gratefully received.

Comment: The code you have requires: `obj.examples = [];` to create an empty array. Inside the loop, you would call `obj.examples.push()` and push `{ sentence: nextwordSentencesArray[i] }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not take the complete object for pushing and a mapping of `nextwordSentencesArray` with the wanted properties?

```
words.push({
    word: "nextword",
    definition: "nextword definition",
    examples: nextwordSentencesArray.map(sentence => ({ sentence }))
});
```